# Error :Call to a member function result() on boolean

Tags: php, codeigniter

i upload dashboard (codeigniter) to hosting, but i have error in code below:

```
<?php
$conds = array( 'img_type' => 'shop', 'img_parent_id' => $id );
$images = $this->Image->get_all_by( $conds )->result();
?>
```

error :

```
An uncaught Exception was encountered
Type: Error

Message: Call to a member function result() on boolean

Filename: /home/alnibras/public_html/application/views/backend/approves/entry_form.php

Line Number: 144
```

Comment: where does $id get a value? the error message means you are trying to get a result, but there is no result

Comment: When I see this error message here, more often than not `get_all_by` is a passthrough to a MySQL function, most of which return either data or a `false` when they fail. This is most likely your case, too.